# HTML5 <canvas>: Performance implications of drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering if there were any performance differences in using drawImage() on a dynamically created canvas (i.e. document.createElement("canvas")) versus a canvas already created in the DOM (i.e.  tags on a HTML page).

My thinking is that the "slow" part of drawImage() occurs when it actually has to display visuals to the user, though I could be wrong (can't find too much information on this).

Would it be substantially more expensive to draw a group of objects to a canvas in memory followed by a final draw to the "main" canvas than just drawing straight to the latter? I feel like it'd be better to have multiple canvases, at least for organizational purposes.

Related: Does the size of the canvas impact performance if you're only drawing to a subsection of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about Chrome and Firefox I could not find any difference between static and dynamic canvas elements. Mainly the amount of pixels drawImage() handles makes it slow + the current globalCompositeOperation (copy, source-over are fastest). However, the browser has to render the full page, so it is a bad idea to place a stretched (background) image below the canvas.

There is a difference between the canvas attributes width/height and its style width/height attributes. You may have a 300*200 pixels canvas with a style size set to 100%. Then internal drawing speed is same what ever the browsers window size is. Of course display quality is a concern.

You may want to separate drawing (lines, boxes, arcs etc) from blitting (drawImage) and find out what consumes more time in your application. As long there is no need for multiple canvas (image processing, blending videos, etc.) try to avoid drawImage(). Your code - not elements - should help you to deal with 'organizational purposes'.

A fullscreen drawImage() on a 1 GHZ Netbook with 1024x600 pixels takes about 10msec. Doing it twice means there is no way to achieve a display rate of 50Hz. Things getting worse if you target iPhone or Android smartphones.

There is no need to do good-old-double-buffering with canvas, it's already implemented. You are free to update only relevant (dirty) subparts of your canvas element whenever you want and gain essential msecs.

Instead of using multiple canvas there is an option to do all invisible operations on a huge one in different sections - drawImage() with target and source the same. It is easier then to see what is happening while debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I suppose some experiments are in order, as is the case with a lot of new(ish) features.